# HTML carousel with automatic item resizing

Tags: html, carousel, scaling

I'm looking for a HTML carousel to show some logos of partners. 
On a normal screen width I want to display five elements at once, and the carousel should automatically enlarge the third (center) element and minimise the first and fifth (border) elements. 
I looked for an out-of-the-box solution for this but couldn't find anything. Then I started to edit the owl carousel, which is technically possible but still a lot of work because I have to make it responsive. 
Does anyone know an out-of-the-box plugin for this? Would be a great help!

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?uFDx6Gdl .. Here you had the center mode plugin. Hope it will help you...

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for my purposes!